# sIFR 3 - I can't get it to display anything

Tags: sifr, sifr3

I'm trying to implement the latest sIFR.  But I can't get even the simplest of tests to work.  My test page is at http://www.kellymitchelljewelry.com/testsifr.asp.  There should be an sIFR-generated line that says "2nd line" between the first and third lines.  I'm using the examples provided on the sIFR page exactly.

My html looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Kelly Mitchell Fine Jewelry</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="sifr.css" type="text/css">
<script src="sifr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="sifr-config.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
First Line<br><br>
<h1>Second Line</h1>
<br>Third Line<br><br>
</body>
</html>
```

My sifr-config.js looks like this:

```
var cgoth = { src: 'cgoth.swf' };
sIFR.activate(cgoth);
sIFR.replace(cgoth, {
  selector: 'h1'
});
```

My sifr.css file looks like this:

```
@media screen {
  .sIFR-flash {
    visibility: visible !important;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .sIFR-replaced, .sIFR-ignore {
    visibility: visible !important;
  }

  .sIFR-alternate {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .sIFR-replaced div.sIFR-fixfocus {
    margin: 0pt; 
    padding: 0pt; 
    overflow: auto; 
    letter-spacing: 0px; 
    float: none;
  }
}

@media print {
  .sIFR-flash {
    display    : none !important;
    height     : 0;
    width      : 0;
    position   : absolute;
    overflow   : hidden;
  }

  .sIFR-alternate {
    visibility : visible !important;
    display    : block   !important;
    position   : static  !important;
    left       : auto    !important;
    top        : auto    !important;
    width      : auto    !important;
    height     : auto    !important;
  }
}

/*
Place CSS rules for to-be-replaced elements here. Prefix by .sIFR-active
so they only apply if sIFR is active. Make sure to limit the CSS to the screen
media type, in order not to have the printed text come out weird.
*/
@media screen {
  .sIFR-active h1 {
    font-family: Verdana;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 1em;
  }
  */
```

I've tried recreating my swf file just in case I did something wrong, and closely followed the instructions to make sure I didn't leave anything out.

Can someone help me figure what I'm doing wrong?

Tom

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your Flash movie is correct, [opening it directly](http://www.kellymitchelljewelry.com/cgoth.swf) should show "Rendered with sIFR 3" text. Make sure it was exported correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have never been able to get a .swf file exported from Flash to work with sIFR. I've always ended up having to use the online sIFR generator: http://www.sifrgenerator.com/wizard.html

I don't know if my version of Flash (CS3) is just not compatible with sIFR or what... I do always save as version 8 like it says to, and make sure every setting is as it should be, but no luck. However, using that generator always seems to solve it. So if your Flash is jinxed to, you might want to give it a try.